# <a href> not hitting get method in Spring boot

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot

**HTML**

```
<div ng-model="currentUser" id="userContainer">{{currentUser.email}}
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void logout(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            cookie.setValue("");
            cookie.setMaxAge(0);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
        }
    }

    response.sendRedirect("/index.html");

}
```

I am running a Spring boot application and have defined the logout controller as a GET method.
When clicking the Logout Div, the url changes to `http://******.ngrok.io/logout`
but it never hits the Controller method, but when I reload the browser with `http://******.ngrok.io/logout` URL then the controller gets hit and logs me out of application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define href with full context path

in JSP its

```
<a href="${contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>
```

for Thymeleaf

```
<a href="@{/logout}">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

But the reason may be that the API may not be getting called you can try by appending the context path in the href of logout button.

As

Contextpath = "the path your Springboot application is running"

```
<a href"${Contxtpath}/logout"/>
```

Comment: This does not work: as it changes the URL to `http://****.ngrok.io/html/$%7BContextpath%7D/logout'.

Answer (score 0):

As I was using angular js in my project , I changed to ng-click event and defined a binding function in Javascript. This works fine now.

HTML :

```
<div ng-model="currentUser" id="userContainer">{{currentUser.email}}
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a data-ng-click="logout()">Logout</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAvascript:

```
$scope.logout = function(){
    $http.get("/logout").then(logoutCallBack, logoutErrorCallback);
}

function logoutCallBack(){
    $window.location.href = "/index.html";
};
function logoutErrorCallback(){};
```